# OnItemClickListener not working for ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, onclicklistener

Here's the relevant code :

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);                   

          // storing string resources into Array
          String[] menulist = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menulist);      

          // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
          this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, menulist));


          ListView lv = getListView();

          // listening to single list item on click
          lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

                // selected item
                String selected = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

                Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);//This is where the error shows  
                toast.show();

                // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
                /*Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
                // sending data to new activity
                i.putExtra("product", product);
                startActivity(i);*/

            }
          });
```

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Single List Item Design -->
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/listgradient" 
        android:clickable="true"      
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

I've kept the `clickable` attribute `true`. But the `Toast` isn't being displayed. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what do you exactly want to do show the toast or click on text view as because question is for clicking on listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
String selected = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_textView_item_id)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: I tried this,your logic seems right.But, I think there's some issue with the `Toast`, because it isn't being displayed still.

Comment: add some text along with selected and see whether something is displayed in the toast. if not change getApplicationContext() to  Activity.this

Comment: remove this:    
android:clickable="true"

Answer (score 2):

I think your error is here:

```
 String selected = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
```

You should use variable "position" to get the value of the list data.

Comment: I tried this,your logic seems right.But, I think there's some issue with the `Toast`, because it isn't being displayed still.